# How to eager load association on association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have this sort of system:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr :name
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tag_associations, dependent:  :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_associations
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

I would like to do this:

```
user.company.articles.includes(:tags).all
```

Will that eager load all the tags when making the articles query? If not, how do I eager load the tags for each article so that it is not an N+1 query if I do this:

```
company.articles.all.select do |article|
  article.tags.any? do |tag|
    tag.name == 'foo'
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you see in the console when you run that? You should probably see something like Article LOAD, TAG LOAD(list of tag ids). If it didn't eager load you'd see article load, tag load, tag load, tag load, tag load, tag load, tag load, tag load.

I think anyway. but the console output should shed light on wether it's eager loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nest eager load like this.

```
@company = user.company.includes(articles: :tags).all
```

And

```
@company.articles.all.select do |article|
  article.tags.any? do |tag|
    tag.name == 'foo'
  end
end
```